# Problem with expo react native MapView on Android

Tags: react-native, google-maps, expo, android-mapview

I have a problem when using MapView in expo on a project. In expo app everything is ok on both iOS and Android, but when building and publishing the same app to Android apk, no matter if on play store or note when opening the map the app crashes and reloads.

I am using:

- expo 37.0.0
- react-native expo sdk 37.0.1
- react-native-maps 0.27.1

Here is the code:

```
import { PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'expo';
import MapView, { Marker, Callout, CalloutSubview } from 'react-native-maps';

<MapView
  ref={'map'}
  onPress={() => this._mapPress()}
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  style={styles.mapView}
  initialRegion={{
      latitude: mapLat,
      longitude: mapLon,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  }}
>
  {markers.map((marker, i) => (
      <Marker
          key={`marker-${i}`}
          coordinate={marker.latlng}
          stopPropagation={true}
          onPress={e => this._mapMarkerPress(marker)}
      >
          <Image
              resizeMode='cover'
              source={
                  JSON.stringify(this.state.selectedMarker) == JSON.stringify(marker)
                      ? ACTIVE_PIN
                      : INACTIVE_PIN
              }
              style={styles.mapMarker}
          />
      </Marker>
  ))}
</MapView>
```

At first I thought there is a problem with the markers array or with the initial lat long, but removing parts of code i reduced the MapView to this:

```
<MapView
  ref={'map'}
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
>
</MapView>
```

And still not working on apk / live Android, but in ios live works just fine, showing an empty map. 
But in expo app both ios and android everything is fine with or without the markers.

Anyone had this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the google-map-api key?

Comment: Yes, i added it. Otherwise it would not work in ios or in expo on android... Right? Do you think maybe it's a problem with the api key on live? That does not happen in expo?

Comment: You forgot to import 'PROVIDER_GOOGLE' =>> import MapView, { Marker, Callout, CalloutSubview, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from 'react-native-maps'

Comment: It's imported , i forgot to add it in the code in my post.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that in expo on android, everything is fine. The problem is only when building the apk and putting the app in play store.

Comment: can you give me apk so i can debug?

Comment: I think there is a problem with ACTIVE_PIN and INACTIVE_PIN variable can you show me the value of these variable?

Comment: you can also deubg apk. install apk on your android phone then open androidstudio->logcat. there you will get actuall error why your app is crashing

Comment: Sure, I can send you the apk. Tell me how please and where.

Comment: The problem is not from ACTIVE_PIN / INACTIVE_PIN. If I just load an empty map, like this: <MapView
  ref={'map'}
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
>
</MapView> it's still not working...

Answer (score 6):

Found the problem and solved it. The api key from google cloud console was only for web. I made it for ios and android too and problem solved. :)

However this is weird, because in expo development the issue was not present... Only in the build for live.

Answer (score 1):

First add

"config": {
"googleMaps": {
"apiKey": "YOUR_API"
}
},

on your app.json, below "android".

Then you need to checked  your api in your [Google Developer Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis)  and make sure

1. you checked - Application restrictions.
2. add Package name (after you did expo buil:android, go to the app.json and copy your package . ex: "com.name.nameofapp"  )
3. add your SHA-1 certificate- For that you need to Run expo credentials:manager (its look like AD:GR:55:SV:54:VS:45:TE:98)
4. In Api restrictions , check Maps SDK for Android

Save and it's work !

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `markerLat` a `markerLon` parameters and replace this:

```
 initialRegion={{
      latitude: mapLat,
      longitude: mapLon,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  }}
```

with this:

```
 initialRegion={{
      latitude: mapLat,
      longitude: mapLon,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421
  },
      markerLat: Number(48.736279),  
      markerLon: Number(19.146191)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work... The problem is that even if just load a simple map, with no settings, a blank map, so to say... It's not working...